# Can't find text in li under div using BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to get the text in ul under a div in this website: https://www.nccn.org/professionals/physician_gls/recently_updated.aspx

But I only get an empty div. My code was:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.nccn.org/professionals/physician_gls/recently_updated.aspx")

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

_div=soup.find("div",{"id":"divRecentlyUpdatedList"})

element = [i.text for i in b.find("a") for b in _div.find("ul")]
```

The results were:

The HTML file screenshot is as follows: [div and ul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SMVg.png)

Also, there is javascript coming right after the div I am trying to get the content from:

[div and javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Oz0.png)

I also tried get all li like this:

```
l = []
for tag in soup.ul.find_all("a", recursive=True): 
    l.append(tag.text)
```

But the text I got was not what I want. Is the text under that div hidden by the javascript?

Any help is welcome. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what is the text your trying to extract ?

Answer (score 2):

The content is populated into the HTML asynchronously from the endpoint https://www.nccn.org/professionals/physician_gls/GetRecentlyUpdated.ashx, which returns JSON. Since it's populated asynchronously and via JS, `requests` doesn't see its results.

You can request that endpoint directly and parse the JSON instead, eg:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.nccn.org/professionals/physician_gls/GetRecentlyUpdated.ashx")
list = json.loads(page.content)
for item in list['recent_guidelines']:
    print(item['Name'], item['VersionNumber'], item['PublishedDate'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually the opposite of what you guessed: it's that the content inside `<div id="divRecentlyUpdatedList">` is being filled with Javascript after an API call.

When using `requests.get`, any Javascript is not being executed on the website and thus we end up with an empty div. For this, you need to use a library that uses a headless browser so that the Javascript can be executed - for example [`requests-html`](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/):

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.nccn.org/professionals/physician_gls/recently_updated.aspx"

session = HTMLSession()
site = session.get(URL)
site.html.render()

html = site.html.html

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


_div=soup.find("div",{"id":"divRecentlyUpdatedList"})
```

Now in `_div`, you will have the rendered content from the API and you can continue finding the content you wish.